# My keyboard default be change in only my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I dont know how my keyboard default when I input on textfield be changed, it's highter and letter bigger, i just draw simple and no change any setting
I took 2 screen photos, one from my app, one from safari app in simulator.

My app

[image]

Safari

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The two screenshots you have are showing the difference between a `zoomed` and `standard` iPhone display setting. You can switch between the two by going into the system settings app, going to the `Display & Brightness` section, and looking for the `Display Zoom` setting. Your safari screenshot appears to be taken with the `standard` setting, whereas your app screenshot is taken using `zoomed`.

Comment: Thanks for ur supp, but maybe u dont understand my point, sorry if u explain wrong. This cause in my only this app, my keyboard higher and bolder. Seem my app always show keyboard of ios 8 :(

Comment: It's not an issue of the keyboard though, it's the whole app being in zoomed mode instead of standard. I don't know why it is like this, but I don't think you'll find a solution by focusing on the keyboard. Look at the menu bar for example, the time is bigger, the battery symbol is bigger, etc. you need to figure out why your app is displaying zoomed and you'll probably solve this issue.

Comment: tks for discovery the time is bigger, the battery symbol is bigger, and i will change my trend, do not keep fix in keyboard, tks a lot

Comment: i find the reason this problem, my app was created by another person and before apple make ip6, and no retina 4.7 :( so, my lauch image used avaiable with ip5 and when i lauch in ip6, all things x2 size :(. I change my lauchImage for ip6 and ip6+, but all constraint lose :(

Answer (score 0):

Not getting your question exactly. If you want to customize keyboard appearance for particular textfield,

```
[myTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

if for whole app,

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

You can change appearance like,

```
UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault,
UIKeyboardAppearanceDark,
UIKeyboardAppearanceLight,
UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert
```

Update as ask in comment :

select your `textField` from storyboard, from attribute inspector change `keyboard type to default` and i am assuming you are not using any third party library for keyboard. and your status bar seems to right there is no difference i feel with other app's status bar.

hope this will help :)

Comment: Sorry if i explain hard to understand, keyboard in my app seem bolder. If two pic beside eachother, u can see difference, mines higher :(

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/0d79d38.jpg
Do u see the difference?, I want to know why my symbol in status bar (for example, the time is bigger, the battery symbol is bigger) and keyboard are bigger then orther apps.